# How should I use the COALESCE function in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

I've written the following code:

```
UPDATE prueba t2
SET    num = coalesce(t1.n_locnae, 0)
FROM   prueba2 t1
WHERE  t2.utm = t1.utm and t2.sem = t1.sem;
```

but it still includes `null` values in the column `num`.

How can it be solved?

Comment: Please show us your table definition and some example values where your update statement did not work.

Comment: @Bergi The table isn't joined against itself.  There is `prueba` and `prueba2` in their example.

Comment: @ThomBrown Thanks, I missed the suffix. Weird choice of table name :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have values of `utm` and `sem` in `prueba` that you don't have in `prueba2`, so get filtered out by your UPDATE statement.

You probably need something like (untested):

```
UPDATE    prueba pa
SET       num = coalesce(p2.n_locnae, 0)
FROM      prueba pb
LEFT JOIN prueba2 p2
       ON (pb.utm,pb.sem) = (p2.utm,p2.sem)
WHERE     (pa.utm,pa.sem) = (pb.utm,pb.sem);
```

This should ensure that all `num` values are updated, whether they their key is matched against the join or not.